# How to use constructor in Realm v0.87.1 on Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I want use **`Realm`** version **0.87.1** for **Database** in android, and i create `provider class` to save values but when use this class **constructor** in main class (`activity`) show me this error, please see error from this image : [Error image Link](http://uploads.im/6MvQA.jpg)

**Task_Provider class :**

```
public class Task_Provider extends RealmObject {

    public Task_Provider() {
    }

    public String getAddTask() {
        return addTask;
    }

    public void setAddTask(String addTask) {
        this.addTask = addTask;
    }

    public long getAdded_date() {
        return added_date;
    }

    public void setAdded_date(long added_date) {
        this.added_date = added_date;
    }

    public long getWhen_date() {
        return when_date;
    }

    public void setWhen_date(long when_date) {
        this.when_date = when_date;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public Task_Provider(String addTask, long added_date, long when_date, boolean complete) {
        this.addTask = addTask;
        this.added_date = added_date;
        this.when_date = when_date;
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    private String addTask;
    @PrimaryKey
    private long added_date;
    private long when_date;
    private boolean complete;

}
```

**Main Activity** (Button setOnClickListener) :

```
String addTask = dialog_edit_task.getText().toString();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Task_Provider task_provider = new Task_Provider(addTask, now, 0, false);

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(task_provider);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

How can i fix this problem? tnx all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try cleaning your project? I got with that issue, but disappeared as i cleaned it. You have an empty constructor already :)

Otherwise, you can try to create the object realm defaults.
Because copyToRealm... your Task_Provider object is already a realm object, since you are extending it on the class declaration.

```
Task_Provider task = realm.createObject(Task_Provider.class);
task.setAddTask("");
...
```

Hope it helps!